# Getting a value in a subreport based on another value in Crystal Reports 2013

Tags: crystal-reports, formula

We are a manufacturer and I have a report that displays costs on a stock code for the current job number that was just completed in the timeframe specified (one working day prior to current date).  I want to display the last job that was completed for the stock code and the cost that was associated to that job.

I have started this in a subreport that will only print the line I need, but I keep getting zeros and not the actual data I need.

the link to the subreport is the stockcode and the job numbers are in ascending order but not necessarily sequential as other jobs happen between stockcodes.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
LOCAL NUMBERVAR UCOST;
LOCAL NUMBERVAR LASTJOB;
LASTJOB =(TONUMBER(NTHLARGEST (2,{InvMovements.Job})));

WHILE LASTJOB = TONUMBER({InvMovements.Job}) DO
(
UCOST = {InvMovements.EnteredCost};
);
LASTJOB;
UCOST
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a variable as `LOCAL` in crystal reports, the scope of the variable is limited to the function or formula field it is declared within.

Try declaring your variables as `SHARED` instead if you want to share their values between the main report and the subreport.  There is also a `GLOBAL` scope as well, but it only allows the values to be shared within the local report, leaving your subreport out of scope for the variable.

Comment: It isn't the variables that are the issue, I am displaying the sub report and it still doesn't work.